# How Can I Fix the Boot Process Reboot Hang?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm installing Ubuntu 17.10 on a Thinkpad 11e.
I had to use a USB keyboard to install 17.10, so a good guess is that the drivers were not available for the keyboard.

Anyway, after I managed to install 17.10, and it asked me to reboot the system. As I did, the system just hung.

First, it says no caching mode found, then it says "assuming drive cache: write through", then it says "Starting Daemon for power management.."
Followed by starting a bunch of different processes apparently.

Then it stops here:
        A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up 
        (24s/ no limit)

What does that mean and how can I rectify the situation? Also, how can I recify the drivers after I fix the boot process?

Answer (score 3):

> Then it stops here: A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (24s/ no limit)

The "24s" value should be increasing, if `systemd` is still alive - is it increasing? (Is the system hung, or just stuck waiting for something that never completes?)

The message means `systemd` is waiting for the previous start-up steps to complete before enabling login. But for some reason, at least one of those previous start-up steps is not reaching a "running" or "completed" state.

One way to find out more would be to just look at the *previous* messages to see what might not be reaching a good state.

Another would be to use the rescue mode boot from the Ubuntu installation media to access the system, and then create the `/var/log/journal/` directory if it does not exist - that makes `systemd` write persistent logs. You can then make a boot attempt, wait until it reaches the problem state, and then do another rescue mode boot to view the logs. The following commands should be helpful in viewing systemd logs:

- `journalctl --list-boots` shows each boot that has persistently-stored logs, and the index number for each.
- `journalctl -xb <number>` shows the `systemd` journal for the specified boot instance. The default for `<number>` is 0 for the most recent boot, but you might want to also try -1 (= the boot attempt before the most recent one) if the `journalctl --list-boots` indicates it exists.